# Fractal alternative to correlation

Tags: correlation, fractal

I am looking for a fractal-based statistical measure which could be used as alternative to correlation between two variables (I know that hurst exponent can be used for auto-correlation).

Is anyone aware of such measures?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit about the purpose/context of this particular analysis, or why do you seek an alternative measure of association?

Answer (score 5):

I doubt you're going to find a single answer to this, given the space of fractal dimensions.  Most papers (in physics, geology) looking at correlation simply stick to a Pearson correlation with fractal math reserved for identifying dimension/self-similarity, etc.

But you might be interested  in the following papers which use a "Correlation Fractal Dimension" as a similarity metric.  The second paper mentions a fractal clustering algorithm which employs this metric.

- [Estimating the Selectivity of Spatial Queries Using the `Correlation' Fractal Dimension](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.4521) (Belussi, Faloutsos, 1995)
- [Characterizing Datasets Using Fractal Methods](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~nivio/cursos/pa03/seminarios/seminario3/seminario3.ps) (Abrahao, Barbosa, 2003)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @ars that you are unlikely to get one answer for this (you may also have more success on http://mathoverflow.net, since our community tends to be more applied, while this technique would have very little real-world usage).  The Abrahao/Barbosa paper is a good reference.  Just to provide some additional sources:

This paper looks at the correlation between fractal dimensions, which seems like a reasonable approach to the problem.

- ["The correlation of fractal structures in the photospheric and the coronal magnetic field"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3950) (Dimitropoulou, Georgoulis, Isliker, Vlahos, Anastasiadis, Strintzi, Moussas 2009)

This paper uses the multi-fractal spectra to estimate correlation:

- ["Continuous wavelet transform based time-scale and multi-fractal analysis of the nonlinear oscillations in a hollow cathode glow discharge plasma"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4844) (Nurujjaman, Narayanan, Iyengar 2009)

Regarding the "Correlation Fractal Dimension", this paper provides a fast algorithm:

- ["Faster estimation of the correlation fractal dimension using box-counting"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4138) (Attikos, Doumpos 2009)